# Adding elements to an array in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to add elements to array . Am actually passing the values of multiple radio buttons
This is what i have written

```
changeValue(params) {
let yesvalue:any[] = [];
 let novalue:any[] = [];

let param_new_name = params.value.split('-')[0];  //0 is the value which is 
                                                   //similar to yes and no radios
if(params.value.split('-')[1] == "no"){
  novalue.push(param_new_name);
  var yes = yesvalue.indexOf(param_new_name);
  if (yes > -1) {
    yesvalue.splice(yes, 1);
  }

}else if(params.value.split('-')[1] == "yes") {

  yesvalue.push(param_new_name);
  var no = yesvalue.indexOf(param_new_name);
  if (no > -1) {
    novalue.splice(no, 1);
  }

}

console.log(params);
console.log("yes values are"+yesvalue); 
console.log("no values are"+novalue);
```

}

A sample of the passed param contains

```
<input type="radio" ng-reflect-value="11-no" value="11-no" 
  ng-reflect-name="new_0" name="new_0">
```

Another

```
<input type="radio" ng-reflect-value="11-no" value="12-no" ng-reflect-name="new_0" name="new_0">
```

The values of the radio buttons are dynamic that is they have different values which keep on changing

eg `12-yes`, `13-yes`, `12-no`

In the bove console logs the values are always empty, where am i wrong

Comment: which array are you trying to add to ?

Comment: if all the console logs are empty, that would mean the params you passed in are empty?

Comment: The params are not empty, Ive realized the mistake was actually calling the array every time i pass the param ive move it to the top part of the class and now using only this keyword i can easily pass the value